# Why doesn't templatecolumn work in modern toolkit EXTJS

Tags: extjs, grid

I am trying to use templatecolumn in EXTJS modern toolkit. I cannot figure out why `Ext.XTemplate` doesn't work in modern toolkit, because the syntax is not different than that for classic toolkit.

**Code**

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['name'],
    data: [{
        'name': 'Bart',
    }, {
        'name': 'Lisa',
    }, {
        'name': 'Homer',
    }, {
        'name': 'Marge',
    }]
});



Ext.create({
    xtype: 'grid',
    height: 500,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    store: store,
    columns: [
        {text: 'Name',  dataIndex:'name'},
        {
            text: 'Name Styled',
            xtype: 'templatecolumn',
            tpl: new Ext.XTemplate(
                '<div class="myClass">{name}</div>',
            ),
        },        
    ],
});
```

**CSS**

```
.myClass {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: red;
}
```

And for classic toolkit, it renders well:

[image]

but, for modern toolkit, it displays full html text, instead to apply class:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set encodeHtml to false in cell config:

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['name'],
    data: [{
        'name': 'Bart',
    }, {
        'name': 'Lisa',
    }, {
        'name': 'Homer',
    }, {
        'name': 'Marge',
    }]
});

Ext.create({
    xtype: 'grid',
    height: 500,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    store: store,
    columns: [{
        text: 'Name',
        dataIndex: 'name'
    }, {
        text: 'Name Styled',
        // disable enocde in cell
        cell: {
            encodeHtml: false
        },
        // ----
        tpl: new Ext.XTemplate('<div class="myClass">{name}</div>'),
    }, ],
});
```